# Get contents from div id with ajax and tab

Tags: jquery, html, get

i have a jQuery tab with ajax loading.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li a").click(function() {

        $("#ajax-content").empty().append("<div id='loading'><img src='{THEME}/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
        $("#nav li a").removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $.ajax({ url: this.href, success: function(html) {
            $("#ajax-content").empty().append(html);
            }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="test1.html">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="test2.html">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="ajax-content">This is default text, which will be replaced</div>
```

everything is fine and working well, but i need something else.

i just need to get contents from div with answer ID in test1.html and test2.html.
i dont wanna load all the pages.

in those pages i have a div for my answers, my test1.html page:

```
<div>Questions</div>
Some Questions

<div id="answers">Some answers</div>
```

i just need to show and get contents from **id="answers"**
how i can do this?

And how i can add fadein effect after contents is loding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `$.ajax()` call with this:

```
var location = this.href +" #answers";
$("#ajax-content").load(location);
```

See the [jQuery ajax `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) documentation on loading page fragments.

---

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li a").click(function() {

        $("#ajax-content").html("<div id='loading'><img src='{THEME}/images/loading.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");

        $("#nav li a").removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var location = this.href +" #answers";
        $("#ajax-content").load(location);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: not working! could u plase send me a full code? i got syntax error

Comment: @alireza what error? please copy/paste the message from your console

Comment: @alireza sorry I meant the error message lol. Anyway, it looks like you have mis-matched curly brackets in a couple places. See the complete code in my answer.

Comment: @alizera Sure. Keep the `#ajax-content` div hidden, load the content with the ajax call, then fade the div in with `.fadeIn()`. So basically this: `$("#ajax-content").hide().load(...).fadeIn()`; the [jQuery documentation for `.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) has details on controlling the animation speed etc.